# Multiple join with self join in MySQL and split column in row

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, php, phpmyadmin

I have four tables "Commission" , "Vendors", "Accounts" and "comsplitconfig" like

commission Table

```
commissionid    vendorid    accountid   sales   commission
1               V1          A2          2000    100
2               V1          A1          1000    100
3               V2          A4          3000    150
4               V2          A2          4000    200
5               V2          A2          4000    200
6               V2          A5          5000    500

Vendor Table
vendorid    vendorname
V1          VEN1
V2          VEN2
V3          VEN3

Account Table
accountid   accountname parentid
A1          ACC1        NULL
A2          ACC2        A1
A3          ACC3        A6
A4          ACC4        A5
A5          ACC5        NULL
A6          ACC6        NULL
```

comsplitconfig Table

```
vendorid    account_commission  parent_commission
V1          75                  25
V2          50                  50
```

and I wish for the result to be like

```
vendorid    accountid   
V1          A2  
V1          A1          
V1          A1          
V2          A4  
V2          A5  
V2          A2  
V2          A1  
V2          A2  
V2          A1  
V2          A5
```

Using the following query i get thousands of multiple records.

```
SELECT  commission.vendorid , Account.accountid, Account.parentid
    FROM  commission
    INNER JOIN  comsplitconfig  ON comsplitconfig.vendorid = commission.vendorid
    LEFT JOIN  
        ( SELECT  accountaccountid.accountid as oid,
                  accountparentaccountid.accountid as cid
            FROM  Account accountaccountid, Account accountparentaccountid
            WHERE  accountaccountid.accountid != vaccountparentaccountid.accountid 
        ) as u1
      ON u1.oid = commission.accountid
              OR  commission.accountid = u1.cid
    inner join  Account
      ON u1.oid = Account.accountid
              or  Account.accountid = u1.cid
```

Result is based on Account Parent id.
if parentid of an account associated to commission record is not NULL then it'll be shown in result as rows(using self join to alias). 
For Example In above Commission table for(commmissionid => 1) V1 vendor A2 account is associated and A2 account's parentid is A1. therefore result for V1 shoulb be

```
vendorid    acountid
V1          A2
V1          A1
```

for commissionid => 2, No V1 and A1 but A1 has no parentid so overall result of Commission for V1 vendor is

```
vendorid    acountid
    V1          A2
    V1          A1
    V1          A1
```